# Where to write ASP code for a textbox in visual studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm new to C#, i searched how to get a transparent background for a textBox and i found this code:

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="textTest" style="background-color: transparent;"></asp:textbox>
```

i need it for the textBox1 in Form4

Comment: Goto Form4.aspx and add/amend the markup that is within that file?

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: presumably you would have a file called Form4.aspx - the page containing the markup for the form. Find "textBox1" and then add the style you want.

Comment: Yes Ric. change the markup

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you have the code for `textBox1` in `Form4` , e.g

```
<asp:textbox runat="server"  id="textBox1">
```

If you can't find this hit `Ctrl + F`, change `Look in:` to Current Project, then search for textBox1.

Change it to:

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" id="textBox1" style="background-color: transparent;">
```

Or in your CSS file add:

```
#textBox1
{
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: In your solution explorer, there will be a Content folder. Look for a CSS file here (maybe called Site.css). Or add a new CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

go to the code view of the form and add the style attribute from the code you found to the textbox1 as shown.

```
    <asp:textbox runat="server" id= "textbox1" style="background-color: transparent;"><asp:textbox>
```

Comment: right click on the form . click option view code. the look for textbox1 markup. and replace the whole line with line in my answer